# insert values using array value dynamically in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I'm having problem to Insert array values into database table. This is my project to create invoice using dynamically added (with js) new rows with array value into database table. 
my code in php(PDO) is as below: 
my form values are as: 
MY COMPLETE CODE IS:

```
<form method="post">
<?php $party = $_GET['party'];  
$sq = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE invoice_id = '$party'");
$ro = $sq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
echo "Invoice for ".$ro->party;
?>
 <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" width="800">
<thead>
<tr>
<th> No </th>
<th> Particulars</th>
<th> Quantity</th>
<th> Price</th>
<th> Discount</th>
 <th> Amount</th>
<th> <input type="button" value="+" id="add" class="btn btn-primary" /> </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="detail">
<input type="hidden" name="invoice_id[]" value="<?php echo $ro->invoice_id; ?>" />
<tr>
<td class="no">1 </td>


<input type="text" class="form-control productname" name="product_name[]" /> 
<td><input type="text" class="form-control quantity" name="quantity[]" /> </td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control price" name="price[]" /> </td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control discount" name="discount[]" /> </td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control amount" name="amount[]" /> </td>
<td> <a href="#" class="remove">Delete </a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="save" value="Save invoice" />



</form>
```

AND I WRITE JAVASCRIPT TO ADD AND DELETE ROW OF ABOVE TABLE TO ADD /DELETE VALUES.

```
<?php 
 if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
$invoice_id = $_GET['party'];
$product_name = $_POST['product_name'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$discount = $_POST['discount'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
for($i;$i<count($_POST['product_name']);$i++){
 $stmt = $conn->query("insert into invoicesubcategory (invoice_id,product_name,quantity,price,discount,amount)
values ('$invoice_id','$product_name','$quantity','$price','$discount','$amount')");

$stmt->bindParam( ':invoice_id', $invoice_id , PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->bindParam( ':product_name', $product_name, PDO::PARAM_STR ); 
$stmt->bindParam( ':quantity', $quantity , PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->bindParam( ':price', $price , PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->bindParam( ':discount', $discount, PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->bindParam( ':amount', $amount , PDO::PARAM_STR );
 header("location:invoicesubcat.php");  
}} ?>
```

I need help, how to insert values, in array, using PDO?
The problem is, my codes, inserting values into db table like this:

```
83  7   Array   Array   Array   0   Array
```

Comment: Have you read a manual? There definitely should be something about `stmt->execute()`

Answer (score 0):

Name your fields like this

```
<input type="text" class="form-control productname" name="data[item1][product_name]" />
<input type="text" class="form-control productname" name="data[item1][amount]" />
...
<input type="text" class="form-control productname" name="data[item2][product_name]" />
<input type="text" class="form-control productname" name="data[item2][amount]" />
```

And then loop over `$_POST['data']` array.

Also you have to use PHP properly. You have to use prepared statements, both for the [proper query formatting](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#prepared) and for the multiple query execution.

```
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into invoicesubcategory
                (invoice_id,product_name,quantity,price,discount,amount)
                values (:invoice_id,:product_name,:quantity,:price,:discount,:amount)");

    foreach($_POST['data'] as $row){
        $stmt->execute($row);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to stick to your structure, you should move assginment inside for loop, and assign like this $quantity = `$_POST['quantity'][$i];`

Comment: I have done, as you have suggested: but, still no value inserted into db table: 
As db table rows view as: 
  Edit  Delete  4  6           0

Comment: I think problem in my case is in field name : 
<input type="text" class="form-control productname" name="data[item1][product_name]" />
Actually, [item1] fields is to be inserted dynamically, not manual.

Comment: If you're using `data[item1][product_name]` names then you have to use the code from my answer, `foreach($_POST['data'] as $row){`.

Comment: Can I send you my whole script including java for adding new rows while creating invoice? than, you can understand for advice me. I'm so much tired to get not working my code as it has to be.
because I;m using : 
<input type="text" class="form-control productname" name="product_name[]" /> 
<td><input type="text" class="form-control quantity" name="quantity[]" /> </td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control price" name="price[]" /> </td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control discount" name="discount[]" /> </td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control amount" name="amount[]" /> </td>

Comment: well you have to use my fist comment here.

Comment: empty values are inserted in table row, with your advice in the comment.

Comment: did you assign ALL the variables this vay?

Comment: Yes I did sir. But, empty values inserted into table rows.
for($i;$i<count($_POST['product_name']);$i++){
         
         $invoice_id = $_GET['party'][$i];
                                $product_name = $_POST['product_name'][$i];
                                $quantity = $_POST['quantity'][$i]; 
        $price = $_POST['price'][$i];
        $discount = $_POST['discount'][$i];
        $amount = $_POST['amount'][$i];

Comment: First. make it work for just one row without loop. Then make it work with static 2 rows without JS. Then start making it with JS. Always use var_dump($_POST) to see the data you get.

Comment: Can I send you my all codes including js to add new rows in html table to hold the field value to be insert into db table using array !!!

Comment: only one row value, inserted very well.

Comment: You cannot send all your codes to me but they say you can send them to http://codementor.io